# I am trying to redirect the page after 5 minutes using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to redirect page after 5 minutes using JavaScript but my code is not working please help me thanks.

**Javascript**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            let my_url = "{{route('non-member-booking')}}";
          
            setTimeout(function() {
                    window.location.replace(my_url);
            }, 300000);
    
    </script>
```

Comment: Your route looks strange, is it your expected route?

Comment: yes this is correct route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code and it will run with no problems.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = 'https://google.com/';
}, 300000);
```